# fix step line responsive css

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

This is what my code produces:

[image]

```
.line {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 34%;
  height: 2px;
  bottom: 36px;
  left: 33%;
}
```

How can I adjust my code to make this line responsive?

Comment: use CSS3 Media Queries

Comment: please can you make a [MCVE] with your current code

Answer (score 0):

```
.line
{
  z-index:5;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 34%;
  height: 2px;
  bottom: 36px;
  left: 33%;
}
.yourcircle class
{
  z-index:4;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/kc1tbu8x/2/

Html:

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="step1">
  <hr/>
</div>

<div class="step2">
  <div class="step2_circles">1</div>
  <div class="step2_circles">2</div>
  <div class="step2_circles">3</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
.wrapper{
  width:30%;
  height:40px;
   display:block;
   position:relative;
}
.step1{
  width:98%;
  z-index:-9999;
  position:absolute;
  top:25%;
  display:block;
  margin:auto;

}
.step2{
  width:100%;
   display:flex;
  display:-webkit-flex;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.step2_circles{
  width:40px;
  height:40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -o-border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -ms-border-radius: 50%;
  background:#ff0000;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:40px;

}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/kc1tbu8x/2/

Answer (score 0):

There is another way, but the flexbox solution above I think is good.
Demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XppLjW

HTML:

```
<div class="steps">
  <span>1</span>
  <span>2</span>
  <span>3</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.steps {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  max-width: 80%;
  margin: 3em auto;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
.steps::before {
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
}
.steps span {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  line-height: 80px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #d4d4d4;
}
.steps span:first-child {
  left: 0;
}
.steps span:nth-child(2) {
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
.steps span:last-child {
  right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try, it's good example

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="number">1</div>
  <div class="number">2</div>
  <div class="number">3</div>
</div>

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: relative;
}

.container:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -1px;
  background:red;
}

.container .number {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: blue;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

JSfiddle example https://jsfiddle.net/4j07gbrd/

Answer (score -1):

you can add mediaqueries to mobile , because stripe can not be 33% center on mobile (whole line 90%)